# Querying current timestamp of cassandra using hector or any java client

Tags: cassandra, hector

Kindly let me know how can we retrieve the current timestamp using hector or any java client

Answer (score 0):

You can get current time using hector using following way

```
long time =TimeUUIDUtils.getTimeFromUUID(TimeUUIDUtils.getUniqueTimeUUIDinMillis());
Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(time);
Date date = new Date(stamp.getTime());
System.out.println(date);
```